# Javascript. How To Efficiently Store Secp256k1 Private Key for ECIES Scheme

Tags: javascript, database, persistent-storage, ecies, secp256k1

I've been having a really hard time figuring out how to store a Secp256k1 privateKey from multiple libraries (currently on this one for ECIES encryption: https://npm.io/package/@toruslabs/eccrypto).

I have tried encoding and decoding with base64, many implementations of functions that copy array buffer for input encoded string to localStoarge and corresponding output Uint8Array from localStorage, I tried it with IndexedDB, JSON.stringify and parse do not work with binary data, and so many more variations.

When I go through the array buffer elements individually to copy it into a new Uint8Array, I get a similar private key, but with two missing key/field's (parent and offset) which I believe is why every library I have tried so far returns something a long the lines of "bad private key" when I try generating the public key from them.

I am exhausted and I would like some professional insight for my lack of skill in this particular subject. So how can I store (in any way as long as it's client/local) a Secp256k1 private key in a way that if I call it from that persistent client sided data base, they can be used to generate the public keys?

Comment: Are you generating the private keys on the client side or the server side?

Comment: I am generating them client sided, and hope to store it (any method is fine) client sided

Comment: Kindly edit your post and tag the "operating system" (mean the JavaScript framework) that you are using as a possible solution depends on that. Kindly add some minimal example code (even when it's failing) and maybe a **sample** Secp256k1 keypair in PEM encoding, thanks. As most solutions rely on PEM encoded = string keys this key format can easily be stored in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the library that uses the private/public key (in this case being [@toruslabs/eccrypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@toruslabs/eccrypto)) requires a buffer parameter for the keys.

A simple solution would be to make the [NodeJS Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) available in the browser, through browserify. You will only need to include the NodeJS Buffer class to the window object when creating the browserify file, as shown:

```js
const eccrypto = require('./index');
window.eccrypto = eccrypto;
window.Buffer = Buffer;
```

Then, generate the bundle file using browserify: `browserify main.js -o bundle.js`

After this, you will be able to use the Buffer class in your browser, which will make loading the private/public key possible. Sample code here:

```html
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  const eccrypto = window.eccrypto;

  const privateKey = eccrypto.generatePrivate();
  const publicKey = eccrypto.getPublic(privateKey);

  // hex string output of private key
  const hexPrivateKey = privateKey.toString('hex')
  console.log(hexPrivateKey); // we can do this as privateKey is a Buffer

  // load private key again
  const newPrivateKey = Buffer.from(hexPrivateKey, 'hex');
 
  const enc = new TextEncoder();

  // code referenced from @toruslabs/eccrypto README
  // Encrypting the message.
  eccrypto.encrypt(publicKey, enc.encode("my testing msg")).then(function (encrypted) {
    // Decrypting the message.
    eccrypto.decrypt(newPrivateKey, encrypted).then(function (plaintext) {
      console.log("Message:", plaintext.toString());
    });
  });
</script>
```

This should be sufficient to store the hex string of the private key in the localStorage or any client-side database/storage that you will be using.

Comment: Thank you for the follow back, I will see if storing the string hexed version of the private key to localStorage works

Comment: That's all I was missing? Wow thank you so much! So when I want to store a privatekey to a string I have to hex it first, then from that hex returns the binary data right?

Comment: The hex string is basically the hex-encoded binary of the keys, you can store it in any format you want, but hex string is a good example for this case.